# Google map API : apply MarkerClusterer only to a category of specific markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

Using MarkerClusterer, I would like to cluster only a category of markers.
I have here 10 markers. I want to cluster only 8 of them, using a "type" variable, that is either "cluster", or "nocluster".

Sounds simple, but I didn't find any tip to do that...
Any idea?

Thank you

```
<script>

    function initMap() {

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 8,
        center: {
          lat: 48.371310,
          lng: 7.593634
        },
        gestureHandling: 'cooperative'
      });

      var markers1 = locations.map(function(location, i) {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: location,
          type: location.type
        });

      });

      // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers. 
      var mcOptions = {gridSize: 50, maxZoom: 10, styles: [{
        anchor:[0,0],
        textSize: 14,
        height: 50,
        width: 50
      }]
    };

      var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers1, mcOptions);

    } /* end FUNCTION initMap */

    var locations = [
            {num: '1', type: 'cluster', lat: 49.050288, lng: 7.950412},
            {num: '2', type: 'cluster', lat: 48.929413, lng: 7.852254},
            {num: '3', type: 'cluster', lat: 48.926529, lng: 7.361955},
            {num: '4', type: 'cluster', lat: 48.892072, lng: 7.655839},
            {num: '5', type: 'cluster', lat: 48.887685, lng: 7.785195},
            {num: '6', type: 'cluster', lat: 48.857382, lng: 7.321078},
            {num: '7', type: 'cluster', lat: 48.856634, lng: 7.319182},
            {num: '8', type: 'cluster', lat: 48.761871, lng: 7.967141},
            {num: '9', type: 'nocluster', lat: 48.736924, lng: 7.709988},
            {num: '10', type: 'nocluster', lat: 48.749944, lng: 7.340100}
          ];

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);

</script>

<script src="js/markerclusterer.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy - if you want a marker to be clustered, then add it to `markerCluster`, otherwise, just use `marker.setMap(map)`.

`google.maps.Marker` will ignore the `type` key that you are passing in because it doesn't do anything with it (moreover, there's no mechanism to retrieve it) so you should probably just create two sets of markers:

```
var markersToCluster = [];
var markersToNotCluster = [];
locations.forEach(function(location, i) {
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:location});
   location.type === 'something' ? markersToCluster.push(marker) : markersToNotCluster.push(marker);
});

var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markersToCluster, mcOptions);
markersToNotCluster.forEach(function(m) { m.setMap(map); });
```